# recode Na and NaN values for specific rows based on column value

Tags: r, dataset

I want to recode NA and NaN values for rows where a column value is X. Here is my data structure.

```
V1  V2  V3   V4  V5  
1   4   9    15  A 
2   12  12   3   B
3  NaN  7    NA  X
```

I want to replace NaN and NA values to 999 where V5 = X

```
V1  V2  V3   V4  V5  
1   4   9    15  A 
2   12  12   3   B
3  999  7   999  X
```

I used the code below, but it is not working

```
df2 <- replace_na(df$V5 == "X", 999)
```

Can someone help?

Comment: I think this is a pure R programming question which you should post in stackoverflow, or at least check there for existing solutions

Comment: ```df[df$V5 == "X"),c("V1","V2","V3","V4")] = "X"``` should work, but if you have a factor for V1,V2,V3,V4, it will fail

Answer (score 0):

You can use e.g. `replace()` from base R for this:

```r
# which rows
df_which <- which(df$V5 == "X")

# replace NAs with 999
df[df_which, ] <- replace(df[df_which, ], is.na(df[df_which, ]), 999)

df
#>   V1  V2 V3  V4 V5
#> 1  1   4  9  15  A
#> 2  2  12 12   3  B
#> 3  3 999  7 999  X
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

#### Data

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = 1:3, V2 = c(4, 12, NaN), V3 = c(9L, 12L, 
7L), V4 = c(15L, 3L, NA), V5 = c("A", "B", "X")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: Thank you, Petr. I am getting the following message when I use that code: "Error in df[df_which, ] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable." Any ideas about why I might be getting that?

Comment: @D.Fowler Is `df` in your case the correct data frame? Use the real name of your data frame... or try to run `class(df)` and let me know.

Comment: Ahh, what a silly mistake on my end. You were correct, I forgot to change the df name. Thank you, Petr. Much appreciated!

Comment: There are NaN values that I also want to code as 999. I tried this: "rest_sleep_3[df_which, ] <- replace(rest_sleep_3[df_which, ], is.nan(rest_sleep_3[df_which, ]), 999)", but I got an error message. Any thoughts on how I could make this work?

Comment: @D.Fowler It should work with my solution as well - try in your R console `is.na(NaN) == TRUE` - and `is.nan()` also should work. Are these NaN values really NaN values or is it only a string "NaN" or something like that?